# Item updated event receiver not firing when workflow updates the list item

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, event-receivers

I have an event receiver on an item updated event, when i manually update the list item, the event receiver is firing and calling the method, but when i update the list item through workflow step,when workflow is approved, it does not fire. i am deploying the solution as a farm solution.

```
public class CreateZohoTicket : SPItemEventReceiver    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An item was updated.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {  
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);

            if ((string)properties.AfterProperties["Status"] == "Approved")
            {               

                CreateTicket(properties);

                //calling a web service POST method in CreateTicket
            }          

        }
```

Comment: Have you used "Set Field in Current Item." tag for updating value in SharePoint designer workflow?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **`Set Field in current item`** action in your **SharePoint designer workflow** to update a list item, it will **not trigger** item updated or any other event receiver in list.

You will have to use **`Update list item`** action in your designer workflow, so when workflow updates your list item, item updated event receiver will be triggered.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hi Dikesh, Thank you for the reply, i am using 'update list item' in the workflow, setting the value of a 'Status' filed to 'Approved' in update list item step.